# using glyph icons in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

Is there any way by which I can use bootstrap's glyph icons in my magento theme? I have no clue on how to use the glyph icons in magento theme

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `bootstrap glyphicons`, you need to include relevant css file in magento and then uses classes to include glyphicon in elements in your templtes. So basically,

1. Put glyphicon specific css file in `skin\frontend\<package>\<theme>\css\bootstrap\bootstrap_glyphicon.css`. (assumes `bootstrap_glyphicon.css` is the bootstrap glyphicon css file).
2. Update your layout with this css

   File: `app\design\frontend\<package>\<theme>\layout\local.xml`

   ```
   <layout>
   <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                 <type>skin_css</type>
                 <name>bootsrap/bootstrap_glyphicon.css</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
   </default>
   </layout>
   ```
3. Use glyphicon specific class in any element in any template

   File : any

   ```
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
   ```

Hope that gives you some idea. Use this to as basis and work out.

Comment: I did it but I get is just a small square at the place where I wanted my icon to get appeared. Do you have some better suggestion?

Comment: make sure you put files in correct package/theme directory

Comment: check for any errors in console